# How to sync my EC2 instance when autoscaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, replication

When autoscaling my EC2 instances for application, what is the best way to keep every instances in sync?

For example, there are custom settings and application files like below...

- Apache httpd.conf
- php.ini
- PHP source for my application

To get my autoscaling working, all of these must be configured same in each EC2 instances, and I want to know the best practice to sync these elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a private AMI which contains scripts that install software or checkout the code from SVN, etc.. The second possibility to use a deployment framework like [chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) or [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/).

The way this works with Amazon EC2 is that you can pass [*user-data*](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-user-data-scripts) to each instance -- generally a script of some sort to run commands, e.g. for bootstrapping. As far as I can see [CreateLaunchConfiguration](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/index.html?API_CreateLaunchConfiguration.html) allows you to define that as well.

If running this yourself is too much of an obstacle, I'd recommend a service like:

- [scalarium](http://www.scalarium.com/)
- [rightscale](http://www.rightscale.com/)
- [scalr](https://scalr.net/) (also [opensource](http://code.google.com/p/scalr/))

They all offer some form of scaling.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for great recommendation! I'll try using chef.